# Hub event not firing after seemingly successful event

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, signalr

I am new to SignalR and working on a very small sample that would potentially allow signature capture fields to be synced across anyone connected to the page. So for instance if two parents and a witness were all using a laptop or a phone/tablet, and all signing at the same time, they could see the signature occurring. This feature would be repurposed for a meeting where everyone is required to sign to verify they were in attendance.

The thing is, I can't see what's wrong. With logging turned on, SignalR doesn't show any apparent errors, and the network panels in Developer Tools show a POST, but nothing ever updates. It just seems like information is being thrown to the server and never propagated back across clients.

I had this sample working at one time, but not sure what I did to break it. The callback for the hub starting up hooks into a jQuery plugin's "OnDrawEnd" event. Also the "clear" button that the plugin generates to clear the signature is hooked into the same event that would regenerate a "cleared" signature. After signing and releasing, the event does fire as the POST happens, but nothing afterwards.

The hub class is below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace InCare.Modules.SignalRSignature
{
    public class SignatureHub : Hub
    {
        public void UpdateModel(SignModel clientModel)
        {
            //addMessage is the client-side function that gets called as a callback
            Clients.All.updateTheSignature(clientModel);
        }
    }
    public class SignModel
    {
        [JsonProperty("outputtedSignature")]
        string SignatureOutput { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The page

```
<!-- References excluded for clarity -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        //Set up a connection
        var signHub = $.connection.signatureHub;
        $.connection.hub.logging = true;
        
        //Default configuration of the SignaturePad plugin
        $signPad = $('.sigPad');
        $api = $signPad.signaturePad();
        
        //Default signature model
        signatureModel = {
            outputtedSignature: ""
        };

        signHub.client.updateTheSignature = function (model) {
            //This is never triggered
            alert ("This method was hit!!")
            signatureModel = model;
            $api.regenerate(signatureModel.outputtedSignature);
        };

        // Start the connection, and when it completes successfully wire up the click handler for the link
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            
            $signPad.signaturePad({
                drawOnly : true,
                onDrawEnd: function () {
                    signatureModel.outputtedSignature = $api.getSignatureString();
                    signHub.server.updateModel(signatureModel);
                }
            });

            $('.clearButton').on("click", function () {
                signatureModel.outputtedSignature = $api.clearCanvas();
                signHub.server.updateModel(signatureModel);
            });

        });
    });
</script>

<h2>Signature Pad test</h2>

<div class="sigPad">
<label for="name">Print your name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="name">
  <p class="typeItDesc">Review your signature</p>
  <p class="drawItDesc">Draw your signature</p>
  <ul class="sigNav">
    <li class="typeIt"><a href="#type-it" class="current">Type It</a></li>
    <li class="drawIt"><a href="#draw-it">Draw It</a></li>
    <li class="clearButton"><a href="#clear">Clear</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="sig sigWrapper">
    <div class="typed"></div>
    <canvas class="pad" width="198" height="55"></canvas>
    <input type="hidden" name="output" class="output">
  </div>
  <button id="linkSubmit" type="submit">I accept the terms of this agreement.</button>
</div>

<div id="regeneratedSignature" style="height:400px;width:400px;"></div>
```

Updated the question with a screenshot using the comments below. After inputting a signature and setting the model's `outputtedsignature` property to the returned JSON string, called the method from the console and received the following input

[image: SignalR Signature Firebug prompt]

#### UPDATE

Running in debug mode, after the callback for onDrawEnd fires, I noticed in the Debug window in VS2012, the following is outputted

```
w3wp.exe Error: 0 : SignalR exception thrown by Task: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Microsoft.Owin.IFormCollection> Microsoft.Owin.OwinRequest.ReadFormAsync()'.
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin.ServerRequest.<ReadForm>d__3.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin.ServerRequest.ReadForm()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Transports.ForeverTransport.<ProcessSendRequest>d__10.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Microsoft.Owin.IFormCollection> Microsoft.Owin.OwinRequest.ReadFormAsync()'.
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin.ServerRequest.<ReadForm>d__3.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin.ServerRequest.ReadForm()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Transports.ForeverTransport.<ProcessSendRequest>d__10.MoveNext()<---
```

Any ideas?

#### UPDATE 2

I tossed this entire project into a new web project, and it worked 100% fine so I know my syntax is good. I'm so confused.

Comment: is your hub method actually being hit? ok, you see some POST in the browser but if you put a breakpoint into public void UpdateModel(SignModel clientModel) does it hit?

Comment: Nope, which also seemed a little odd as there are no exceptions or anything thrown either.

Comment: then this is the reason why other clients does not receive anything. the new question is why it is not being called. try to call the updateModel outside your click event, just to test it. if it is ok then the problem is related to your form and click. btw I don't think you should see any POST in this process (unless you use a setup without websocket support).

Comment: Added a screenshot to the original question.

Comment: What version of SignalR are you using?

Comment: 2.0.0. Didn't bring down -pre either.

Comment: Updated the question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

From exception message, it seems you updated OWIN or SignalR packages and one of the methods referred was no longer available. When you moved to a new project, you fixed the problem by using correct OWIN and SignalR packages.

`` System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Microsoft.Owin.IFormCollection> Microsoft.Owin.OwinRequest.ReadFormAsync()'.
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin.ServerRequest.<ReadForm>d__3.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine) ``

Comment: Any idea how to fix that? Nuget is always bringing down the packages for me and what I've posted in the question is pretty much all of my code involved, so beyond that, I'm stumped.

Comment: Look packages.config and validate all signalr packages are the same version

Comment: Yeah they are all the same version.

Comment: Microsoft.Owin.dll is it net45? if it is net40 then the method is not available

Comment: It is 4.5. Packages.config references 2.0.1 and net45. Project is set to 4.5 Framework and again, all packages are most up to date with Nuget.

Comment: For some unknown reason, your version of Microsoft.Owin.dll does not have the method. I suggest to re-install all nuget packages. If it does not work, could you share contents of packages.config or your vs solution